# Orthogonal complements with matrix and Fields

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, coding-theory

> Let $F= \mathbb{Z_5}$ and $H$ be the following matrix:
>
> \begin{bmatrix}
>     1 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
>     0 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
> \end{bmatrix}
>
> **a)** Determinate one base of the space $C \subset F^4$ of the solutions $x \in F^4$ with $Hx^t=0$
>
> **b)** Verify that $C$ is it's own orthogonal complement.

I have done this so far:

$Hx^t=0 \Leftrightarrow \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
    x \\
    y \\
    z \\
    w \\
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
    0 \\
    0 \\
    0 \\
    0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

$\Leftrightarrow \begin{cases}
x+2y=0 \\
z+2w=0
\end{cases} \Leftrightarrow \begin{cases}
x=-2y \\
z=-2w
\end{cases}$

So I can write as $(-2y,y,-2w,w)$.

So, I can have the following $<(0,0,-2,1),(-2,1,0,0),(-2,1,-2,1)>$

Did I calculated $C$ or $C^\bot?$ I don't understand it.

Also, to verify should I use the fact that $dim(C)+dim(C^\bot)=n$?

**EDIT:**

So, $C=<(0,0,-2,1),(-2,1,0,0),(-2,1,-2,1)>=<(0,0,-2,1),(-2,1,0,0)>$. Now to calculate the orthogonal complement of $C$  I do $\begin{cases} 
(0,0,-2,1) \cdot(x,y,z,w) \\
(-2,1,0,0) \cdot (x,y,z,w)\\
\end{cases} \Leftrightarrow \begin{cases} 
-2z+w=0 \\
-2x+y=0\\
\end{cases} \Leftrightarrow \begin{cases} 
w=2z \\
y=2x\\
\end{cases}  \Leftrightarrow (x,2x,z,2z)$

Therefore we have $C^\bot=<(1,2,0,0),(0,0,1,2)> \neq C=<(0,0,-2,1),(-2,1,0,0)>$

I got to $C \neq C^\bot$ , and they should be the same. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is nothing wrong in your calculation (other than thinking that $C\neq C^\perp$). The vectors $(1,2)$ and $(-2,1)$ of $F^2$ are scalar multiples of each other.

Answer (score 1):

The position of the zero entries clearly show that second row is not a scalar multiple of the first, hence the rank of the matrix is $2$. Having 4 columns, the nullity is $4-2=2$, by the rank-nullity theorem. In your computation you show 3 vectors as basis, which should be corrected. The first two are linearly independent and hence form a basis (for what?). Multiplying this vectors with $H$ we see that $Hx^t=0$ (your notation), so they form a base for the solution space.